# cohomological base change isomorphism hold on a non empty open subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading Lazarsfeld's Positivity in Algebraic Geometry II

In page 312,there is a remark says if $f: V \longrightarrow W$ is any proper morphism of varieties, with $W$ reduced, and if $\mathcal{F}$ is any coherent sheaf on $V$, then there is a non-empty Zariskiopen subset $U \subset W$ such that the natural maps
$$
R^j f_* \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathbf{C}(t) \longrightarrow H^i\left(V_t, \mathcal{F}_t\right)
$$
are isomorphisms for all $j>0$ and $t \in U$.

Proof. In fact, thanks to Grauert direct image theorem it suffices to choose $U$ such that $\mathcal{F}$ is flat over $U$ and all the direct images $R^j f_* \mathcal{F}$ are locally free on $U$.

---

I know  $f$ is proper there exist a dense Zariski open subset $U$ such that $\mathcal{F}|_{f^{-1}(U)}$ is flat over $U$. thus the flatness of $\mathcal{F}$ is guaranteed, on the other hand since $W$ is reduced, the normal locus is dense and coherent sheaf is locally free on the codimension 2 subset of normal scheme, thus we can gaurantee the locally free of $R^jf_*\mathcal{F}$.

The question is when $j$ in the direct image sheaf $R^jf_*\mathcal{F}$ increase, why it's possible to find a uniform neightborhood for all $j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to do it for finitely many $j$ by Grothendieck vanishing: if $j>\dim V$, then $R^jf_*\mathcal{F}=0$ as $H^j(U,\mathcal{F}|_U)=0$ for all open $U$. Now you can take an intersection of finitely many dense open sets.

Comment: Thank you KReiser